# How to select max numeric value out of numeric characters?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, max, min

I have a dataset where I have grouped by a `Gene` column. Some values grouped into each row are just `.,` so I remove them, leaving only several numeric characters per row and column.

To do this am coding:

```
#Group by Gene:
data <- setDT(df2)[, lapply(.SD, paste, collapse = ", "), by = Genes]

#Remove ., from anywhere in the dataframe
dat <- data.frame(lapply(data, function(x) {
  gsub("\\.,|\\.$|\\,$|(, .$)", "", x)
}))
```

My data before removing `.,` and after grouping by `Gene` looks like:

```
Gene    col1                     col2                  col3           col4
ACE     0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5       .                      ., ., .        1, 1, 1, 1, 1
NOS2    ., .                     .                      ., ., ., .     0, 0, 0, 0, 0
BRCA1   .                                               ., .           1, 1, 1, 1, 1
HER2    .                        0.1, ., .,  0.2, 0.1   .              1, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

After removing `.,` my data looks like:

```
Gene    col1                 col2               col3     col4
ACE     0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5                               1, 1, 1, 1, 1
NOS2                                                     0, 0, 0, 0, 0
BRCA1                                                    1, 1, 1, 1, 1
HER2                         0.1,      0.2, 0.1          1, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

I am now trying to select the minimum or maximum value per row and column.

Expecting example output:

```
Gene    col1                 col2            col3    col4
ACE     0.5                                           1
NOS2                                                  0
BRCA1                                                 1
HER2                          0.1                     1

#For col1 I need the max value per row (so for ACE 0.5 is selected)
#For col2 I need the min value per row
```

For note, my actual data is 100 columns and 20,000 rows - different columns need either max or min values per gene selected.

However with the code I use I am only getting the expected output for `col4` and my other columns repeat the selected value twice (I am getting `0.5, 0.5` and `0.1, 0.1` and I can't figure out why).

The code I am using to select min/max values is:

```
#Max value per feature and row
max2 = function(x) if(all(is.na(x))) NA else max(x,na.rm = T)
getmax = function(col) str_extract_all(col,"[0-9\\.-]+") %>%
  lapply(.,function(x)max2(as.numeric(x)) ) %>%
  unlist() 

#Min value per feature and row
min2 = function(x) if(all(is.na(x))) NA else min(x,na.rm = T)
getmin = function(col) str_extract_all(col,"[0-9\\.-]+") %>%
  lapply(.,function(x)min2(as.numeric(x)) ) %>%
  unlist() 

data <- dt %>%
  mutate_at(names(dt)[2],getmax)

data <- dt %>%
  mutate_at(names(dt)[3],getmin)

data <- dt %>%
  mutate_at(names(dt)[4],getmax)
```

Why aren't these selection functions working for all my columns? All columns are character class. I'm also wondering if I even need to remove `.,` at all and can just jump straight to selecting the max/min value per row and column?

Example input data:

```
structure(list(Gene = c("ACE", "NOS2", "BRCA1", "HER2"), col1 = c("0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5", 
"", "", ""), col2 = c("", "", "", "  0.1,      0.2 0.,1"), col3 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA), col4 = c("                         1, 1, 1, 1, 1", 
"                                     0, 0, 0, 0, 0", "                                     1, 1, 1, 1, 1", 
"     1, 1, 1, 1, 1")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: I am unsure where your data starts, but it may be more efficient to do ```dt[, lapply(.SD, max), Gene]```. Since your data seems to be a character, using the function ```function(x) max(as.numeric(x), na.rm = TRUE)``` may help. Basically, try to see if you can skip collapsing followed by the regex by directly applying functions to your raw data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `type.convert` and set its argument `na.strings` to `"."`. You may also want to use the `range` function to get both min and max in one shot.

Assume that your `data.table` looks like this

```
> dt
    Gene               col1                 col2       col3          col4
1:   ACE 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5                    .    ., ., . 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
2:  NOS2               ., .                    . ., ., ., . 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
3: BRCA1                  .                            ., . 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
4:  HER2                  . 0.1, ., .,  0.2, 0.1          . 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

Consider a function like this

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)

get_range <- function(x) {
  x <- type.convert(str_split(x, ",\\s+", simplify = TRUE), na.strings = ".")
  x <- t(apply(x, 1L, function(i) {
    i <- i[!is.na(i)]
    if (length(i) < 1L) c(NA_real_, NA_real_) else range(i)
  }))
  dimnames(x)[[2L]] <- c("min", "max")
  x
}
```

Then you can just

```
dt[, c(Gene = .(Gene), lapply(.SD, get_range)), .SDcols = -"Gene"]
```

Output

```
    Gene col1.min col1.max col2.min col2.max col3.min col3.max col4.min col4.max
1:   ACE      0.3      0.5       NA       NA       NA       NA        1        1
2:  NOS2       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA        0        0
3: BRCA1       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA        1        1
4:  HER2       NA       NA      0.1      0.2       NA       NA        1        1
```

Note that there is no need to do it by `Gene` as the function `get_range` is already vectorised.